# For any graph there exists a partition $(V_1,V_2)$ such that $G[V_1]$ and $G[V_2]$ is even.

Tags: graph-theory

Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph.
Show: There is a partition of the vertices $(V_1,V_2)$ such that $G[V_1]$ is even and $G[V_2]$ is even.

$G[V_i]$ is the graph consisting of the vertices $V_i$ with all egdes from E that have both ends in $V_i$.

Might have something to do with the edge space, cycle space and/or cut space...

Comment: What is $G[V]$ here?

Comment: sorry, I'll edit the question and explain...

Comment: What is an even graph?

Comment: What is it that should be even in an even graph?

Comment: As a hint for finding a solution, I think this is known as Gallai's cycle-cocyle partition theorem.

Comment: A graph is called even if all its vertices have an even degree (I think this is equivalent to the graph being eulerian, at least for connected graphs)...